# I can’t send the image using the post request and from the Volley library in the Kotlin programming language

Tags: android, kotlin, request

I’m developing a mobile application that sends photos to the server using a post request with a key. Do not get to send this very request. I would be grateful for any help!

The error "Com.android.volley.TimeoutError" is displayed in the application
error snapshot:
[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

But why are you using Volley any specific reason ?? i suggest to use retorfit and with that user requestbody with multipart, it should help you.